# How to replace a character in a string in C?

Tags: c, string

I'm writing a function that replaces a given character by '#' in a string.  The function should return a pointer to the position that follows the just-replaced character. Also, the string is not NULL terminated, it ends with '#'. the string can't be copied, it should be modified itself. By now I have the following:

```
char *es_token(char *s, char c)
{
int i = 0;
while(s[i] != '#'){
    if (s[i] == c){
       putchar('#');
       i++;
    }
    else{
        return 0;
    }
}

return (char*)(s);
}
```

I don't know how in this case to return a pointer. I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: Use `gdb` or some sort of debugger to check what your program is doing exactly.

Comment: Should you replace all the occurrence of the character or only the first occurrence ?

Comment: `putchar()` is not appropriate here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A pointer to character `i` in a C string `char *s` is the address of that entry:

```
&s[i]
```

Given that `s[i]` is just shorthand for `*(s + i)` the above is the same as:

```
s + i
```

Other issues with your code:

- `putchar` writes a single chacater to the termnal. It doesn't replace anything in the string. For that, use `s[i] = '#'`
- Your `return` statements are the wrong way round: Return the desired pointer when you have found what you look for and 0 otherwise, when you have checked the whole string.
- Your last `return` has a uasless cast. Don't do that, because a cast can hide warnings and errors about incompatible types.

So:

```
char *es_token(char *s, char c)
{
    int i = 0;

    while(s[i] != '#') {
        if (s[i] == c) {
            s[i] = '#';
            return &s[i + 1];
        }
        i++;
    }

    return NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that the memory of your string `s` is not protected from writing (i.e. it's not a string literal) you can do it like this:

```
if (s[i] == c){
   s[i] = '#';
   return &s[i+1]; // This produces a pointer to (i+1)'st character of s
} else {
    i++;
}
```

This returns a pointer to the character after the one you replaced.

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/3XivTE)

Comment: Or simply `return (s + i + 1);`

Answer (score 1):

```
char *es_token(char *s, char c)
{
int i = 0;
while(s[i] != '#'){
    if (s[i] == c){
       s[i] = '#';
       return s+i+1;
    }
    i++;
}

return NULL;
}
```

A pointer is just a position in memory. If you return `s+i+1` the compiler will take the address `s` (beginning of the string), and it will add `i+1` to it, calculating the address of the position you just replaced, plus one.

Answer (score 1):

I interpret your code as you want to terminate search if you find the character in `c` or the character literal `#`. Then:

```
char *es_token(char *s, char c) {
    int i = 0;
    while(s[i] != '#') { // as long as not #
        if (s[i] == c) { // if the current char is c
           s[i] = '#'; // change it to #
           break; // and stop searching
        }
    }
    // invariant: i is the position of a #
    return s+i+1; // +1 gets the position after
}
```